# Use multiple gateway with SMSLIB

Tags: java

I want use multiple gateway to send messages with SMSLIB.

I have 4 HSPA modems and for each one a different operator, how to detect the name of operator and from there using a specific SMS to be sent.

Here my code:

```
// SendMessage.java - Sample application.
//
// This application shows you the basic procedure for sending messages.
// You will find how to send synchronous and asynchronous messages.
//
// For asynchronous dispatch, the example application sets a callback
// notification, to see what's happened with messages.

package sms;

import org.smslib.AGateway;
import org.smslib.IOutboundMessageNotification;
import org.smslib.Library;
import org.smslib.OutboundMessage;
import org.smslib.Service;
import org.smslib.modem.SerialModemGateway;

public class SendMessage
{
        public void doIt() throws Exception
        {
                OutboundNotification outboundNotification = new OutboundNotification();
                System.out.println("Example: Send message from a serial gsm modem.");
                System.out.println(Library.getLibraryDescription());
                System.out.println("Version: " + Library.getLibraryVersion());
                SerialModemGateway gateway = new SerialModemGateway("modem.com3", "COM3", 115200, "Huawei", "");
                gateway.setInbound(true);
                gateway.setOutbound(true);
                gateway.setSimPin("0000");
                // Explicit SMSC address set is required for some modems.
                // Below is for VODAFONE GREECE - be sure to set your own!
                gateway.setSmscNumber("+947500001");
                Service.getInstance().setOutboundMessageNotification(outboundNotification);
                Service.getInstance().addGateway(gateway);
                Service.getInstance().startService();
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Modem Information:");
                System.out.println("  Manufacturer: " + gateway.getManufacturer());
                System.out.println("  Model: " + gateway.getModel());
                System.out.println("  Serial No: " + gateway.getSerialNo());
                System.out.println("  SIM IMSI: " + gateway.getImsi());
                System.out.println("  Signal Level: " + gateway.getSignalLevel() + " dBm");
                System.out.println("  Battery Level: " + gateway.getBatteryLevel() + "%");
                System.out.println();
                // Send a message synchronously.
                OutboundMessage msg = new OutboundMessage("0094757599108", "Hello from SMSLib!");
                Service.getInstance().sendMessage(msg);
                System.out.println(msg);
                // Or, send out a WAP SI message.
                //OutboundWapSIMessage wapMsg = new OutboundWapSIMessage("306974000000",  new URL("http://www.smslib.org/"), "Visit SMSLib now!");
                //Service.getInstance().sendMessage(wapMsg);
                //System.out.println(wapMsg);
                // You can also queue some asynchronous messages to see how the callbacks
                // are called...
                //msg = new OutboundMessage("309999999999", "Wrong number!");
                //srv.queueMessage(msg, gateway.getGatewayId());
                //msg = new OutboundMessage("308888888888", "Wrong number!");
                //srv.queueMessage(msg, gateway.getGatewayId());
                System.out.println("Now Sleeping - Hit <enter> to terminate.");
                System.in.read();
                Service.getInstance().stopService();
        }

        public class OutboundNotification implements IOutboundMessageNotification
        {
                public void process(AGateway gateway, OutboundMessage msg)
                {
                        System.out.println("Outbound handler called from Gateway: " + gateway.getGatewayId());
                        System.out.println(msg);
                }
        }

        public static void main(String args[])
        {
                SendMessage app = new SendMessage();
                try
                {
                        app.doIt();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```

This one detect only one gateway from COM3, but i have a USB SWITCHER in COM3 and 4 modems on it.

What is the method to use to get them detected (I want a method to do it), thank you so much.

Comment: As for detecting them - there is sample code in the smslib source for decting modems attached to ports. As to determining the provider; I don't think there's an API to read, if you can send a custom AT command, you should be able to get the operator (e.g. `AT+CIMI` gets the IMSI, which has the mobile operator code embedded in it)

Comment: Although, reading some examples it indicates that you can call `getImsi()` on the `SerialModemGateway` instance, which will have the same behaviour.