# SMSLib sending message, using multiple gateways

Tags: java, sms-gateway, smslib

I'm using SMSLib for sending and receiving messages. Everything's working great, but now I'd like to plug more than one modem. I want to receive messages by all of my modems and do something with them (I can do that, I think). I also want to send messages, but only through the selected modem (there's my problem). Until I had one gateway i did sending like this:

```
OutboundMessage msg = new OutboundMessage(recipientNumber, text);
Service.getInstance().sendMessage(msg);
```

But now, how can I select the one specific gateway, that I want to use to send my message?

I found a topic with a problem a bit like mine, but not exactly:
[Use multiple gateway with SMSLIB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35289518/use-multiple-gateway-with-smslib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each modem is a AGatway object in SMSLib so you need to set it up first:

```
SerialModemGateway modemGateway = new  SerialModemGateway("FirstGateway", "/dev/ttyM0", "9600", "WAVECOM", "Fastrack");
Service.getInstance().addGateway(modemGateway);
```

Where **FirstGateway** is ID of your modem which is called **gatewayId** in SMSLib. All you have to do now is pass your gatewayId to *sendMessage* method or *queueMessage* (if you send messages asynchronously):

```
OutboundMessage msg = new OutboundMessage(recipientNumber, text);
Service.getInstance().sendMessage(msg, "FirstGateway");
```

or:

```
OutboundMessage msg = new OutboundMessage(recipientNumber, text);
msg.setGatewayId("FirstGateway");
Service.getInstance().sendMessage(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

I didnt notice that there is such a method sendMessage() which takes gatewayId as a second agrument. If so, there will be perfect. I'll check that tomorrow, are you sure about that? I'm using SmsLib 3.x

**EDIT:**

It's exactly as you said. I just put gatewayId as a second argument and it's working. Another options is that you can set gatewayId of created OutboundMessage:

```
OutboundMessage msg = new OutboundMessage(recipientNumber, text);
msg.setGatewayId("FirstGateway");
Service.getInstance().sendMessage(msg);
```

So easy.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would't use ***sendMessage*** method with multiple gateways, use ***queueMessage*** it adds your msg to SMSLib service queue and sends it asynchronously.

Also , if you start your application with:

```
-Dsmslib.queuedir=yourQueuedMessagesDirectory
```

you will be able to store all unsent messages on hard drive and give SMSLib service facility to send them after application restart.

Comment: I've never used queueMessage, but I'll check how it works. I'm planning to put outgoing messages in a database table, run a task for example once a minute, send them and change their status if they were sent properly.
And there is a place to use queueMessage and  IOutboundMessageNotification, which I won't be able to use when sending via sendMessage. Cool ! :-)